# Groups Each of the Input Array's Elements by First Character and Return as an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following task

> Given an array of strings, write a function that returns an object that groups each of the input array's elements by the first character.

My code is below. I'm getting an error ((highlighted with comment) saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Could someone explain to me why it is saying it's undefined?

```js
function groupBy(arr) { 
  var result = {};
  var container = []
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = arr[i];
    var firstChar = currentWord[0];
    var nextWord = arr[i + 1];
    var secondChar = nextWord[0]; // Error here

    if (firstChar === secondChar) {
      container.push(currentWord, nextWord)
    } else {
      container.push(currentWord)
    }

    result[firstChar] = container;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(groupBy(['apple', 'cat', 'boat', 'card', 'bond']));

// returns { 'a': ['apple'], 'c': ['cat', 'card'], 'b': ['boat', 'bond'] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is breaking at

```
var nextWord = arr[i + 1];
```

Set the for loop till arr.length-1

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
```

Comment: That worked! Why couldn't I see that?! Wish I could have seen that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It can essentially be done in a one-liner:

```js
function groupBy(arr){return arr.reduce((a,c)=>((a[c[0]]=a[c[0]]||[]).push(c),a), {}) };
console.log(groupBy(['apple', 'cat', 'boat', 'card', 'bond']));
```

The work is done in this expression:

```
arr.reduce((a,c)=>((a[c[0]]=a[c[0]]||[]).push(c),a), {})
```

In this `.reduce()` call I assemble an object with keys taken from the first letter of each array element `c[0]`. I check, whether a property with this key already exists by applying the `||` operator:

```
=a[c[0]]||[]
```

In case the key alreay exists ( `a[c[0]]` is "truthy" ) the already established array will be returned, otherwise a new array is created (`[]`)and stored under this property. Then `c` (the current array element) is pushed onto this `a[c[0]]` -array with `.push(c)`. After that a comma and `a` follows: the accumulated object is returned as the result of the `reduce()`-callback function.

Comment: Wow, I'm not there yet! An absolute beginner here so having a hard time understanding your solution but thanks for your input/help!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code it may be due to when it gets to the last word 'bond' since there is nothing after it says it's undefined. You may want to mitigate that with something like if arr[i + 1] is true then set your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to look at both the `currentWord` and the `nextWord` when grouping.  Just let the object do its normal thing, which is using sorted key pairs, by pushing `word` onto `result[firstChar]`.  To quote MDN Documentation...

> The Object class represents one of JavaScript's data types. ***It is used to store various keyed collections***... (Emphasis mine.) (Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).)

```js
function groupBy(arr) { 
  var result = {};
  var container = []
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = arr[i];
    var firstChar = currentWord[0];
    if(!result[firstChar]) {
        result[firstChar] = [];
    }

    result[firstChar].push(currentWord);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(groupBy(['apple', 'cat', 'boat', 'card', 'bond']));

// returns { 'a': ['apple'], 'c': ['cat', 'card'], 'b': ['boat', 'bond'] }
```

The previous snippet gives this result for me...

```
{
  "a": [
    "apple"
  ],
  "c": [
    "cat",
    "card"
  ],
  "b": [
    "boat",
    "bond"
  ]
}
```

Comment: if(!result[firstChar]) - can i ask you for a bit of explanation here? What does this mean? Sorry, an absolute beginner here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, sure, Ycfan23.  The object starts out as just `{}`.  There's no `{"a":[]}`, yet.  That if statement is saying "if we don't have an array for firstChar, yet, then make one".  You'll notice you have no "d" or "e" arrays, yet, but with the above code, if you added an e-word, it would automatically appear in the object.  make sense?

Comment: I see. That makes a lot sense! Thanks again man!

Comment: @ycfan23: No problem, any time!  By the day, don't forget to mark the answer that helped you the most as correct, that will help others who have this same problem in the future. Thanks!